# Scrollbar area is just blue on site in Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I recently converted a site created using Intuit's sitebuilder to WordPress (so don't ask about the design/music ;) ).

I'm having a strange issue, and several google searches and stackoverflow searches have returned nothing about it.

I'm using Chrome 16 and on all the pages of this website, I get blue bars instead of normal scrollbars. I have no CSS/scripts for custom scrollbars on the site. I'm guessing it's a weird Chrome css overflow: problem.

Anyone seen it before or have any suggestions?

http://razorsix.andrewsfreeman.com/origins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something in your `<embed>` code. Try removing it and you'll see. Not sure what's causing it though..?

`<embed src="http://razorsix.andrewsfreeman.com/wp-content/themes/RazorSix for Wordpress/mp3s/shambala.mp3" autostart="true" loop="true" height="0" width="0">`

Seems like the browser "crashes" on it. Maybe a file error in the MP3...

Comment: If the browser crashes, it's a Chrome issue, not a MP3 issue.

Comment: Because all browsers have exactly the same behaviour?

Comment: Weird. Thanks for identifying it. o.o