# chrome scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Why, when I insert embed code in site, the chrome scrollbar turns a blue bar? How can I fix it? It just turns into a blue bar, and I can't figure out how to fix it. Will be thankful if you would give me some solution for it, since I've searched whole internet and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the margin from `#border` div.

```
#border {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I don't know why but that got rid of the blue bar for me.

**EDIT:**

That just fixes the overflow. It looks like an issue with chrome:

[Scrollbar area is just blue on site in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548832/scrollbar-area-is-just-blue-on-site-in-chrome)

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45965